# KUKA Experimental + MoveIt

Tags: ros, kuka, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I had downloaded the KUKA Experimental package (https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental) and set up a package to connect with a KUKA KR180 R2900 via RSI with KRC4.
The setup is made based on the example package there with the KR6.
The connection was successful. I could control the robot but the movement was so jerky. The connection was away after the jerk happened there.

Does anybody have the same issue? Or has anybody made it to control the KUKA Robot with the same communication protocol?

Can anybody help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377382/kuka-experimental-+-moveit/) by [tjoa](https://answers.ros.org/users/51149/tjoa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What robot model are you using? Your real robot and your virtual robot should be the same. If you are using a different robot, then your results may differ.

> set up a package to connect with a KUKA KR180 R2900 via RSI with KRC4

It is essential to check the moments, and rotation is perfect. In some cases, the rotation of the real robot and your URDF robot may differ. Moreover, you also need to check the angle of moments of each axis makes it the same as Kuka real robot. You can check by importing the URDF file to RVIZ and check each axis working.

You can follow these steps to check links:

1. https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial Clone It
2. Copy display.launch file from urdf_tutorial/launch folder.
3. In your launch folder, where you have built the package, create a launch file and paste display. Just change the URDF path and file name.
4. Test the above details.

> I could control the robot but the movement was so jerky.

Over here you can check your axis degree from the robot and from rviz and compare it whether it is different to not. If yes, then you need to fix your links from the URDF file.

You can check so: In your smart pad goto setting -> Display -> Actual position

[image: image description]

Compare this with your RVIZ motion planning -> Joints tab

[image: image description]

Feel free to comment.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tjoa](https://answers.ros.org/users/51149/tjoa/) on 2021-04-30**:
Hi Ranjit,

the URDF has been configured via the CAD Data with the Solidworks tool for URDF. The joint limits, orientations, etc are derived from KUKA documentation.

The actual pose is also corresponding to the pose that shows in RViz (MoveIt).

Have you change something with PREEMPT RT? Or anything inside the KRL files?

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-04-30**:
Can you please tell me which version of RSI are you using?

**Comment by [tjoa](https://answers.ros.org/users/51149/tjoa/) on 2021-04-30**:
Dear Ranjit,

I am using RSI 3.3.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-04-30**:\

> anything inside the KRL files?

Then your KRL file is perfect, if your RSI version is 4 then only you have to change KRL files.

> but the movement was so jerky.

Can you please! tell me exactly what is happening? For eg. I am turning my robot to go left it is going in the right direction etc. You can edit questions and upload a photo or add a youtube link. Note: the more details will be provided by you can help me with more clues and answer your question properly.

> Have you change something with PREEMPT RT?

What is this I don't know much about it?

Did you try in simulation mode by using sim:=true? Does it work perfectly with the indestrrial_core package?